# FizzBuzz in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, fizzbuzz

You need to write a query that outputs a sequence of digits from 1 to 1000.

If the number is a multiple of three, then `Fizz` is output **instead** of a number. If it is a multiple of five, then `Buzz`, and if both three and five, then [`FizzBuzz`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz).

My pseudocode:

```
SELECT
   CASE
     WHEN (BETWEEN 1 AND 1000)% 3 = 0 THEN "Fizz",
     WHEN (BETWEEN 1 AND 1000)% 5 = 0 THEN "Buzz",
     WHEN (BETWEEN 1 AND 1000)% 5 = 0 AND WHEN (BETWEEN 1 AND 1000)% 3 = 0 THEN "FizzBuzz",
   END
```

Comment: Please add tag for specific DBMS that you are using

Comment: Using PostgreSQL

Comment: Is this some kind of homework or exam question? If yes, then it would be good to mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this query

```
SELECT
   n,
   CASE
     WHEN MOD(n,15) = 0 THEN 'FizzBuzz'
     WHEN MOD(n,3) = 0 THEN 'Fizz'
     WHEN MOD(n,5) = 0 THEN 'Buzz' 
     ELSE ''
   END
FROM generate_series(1,1000) n
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/QJeWV1e5)

Answer (score 0):

Plain [`case`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) statement:

```sql
select case when num%15=0 then 'FizzBuzz' 
            when num%3 =0 then 'Fizz'
            when num%5 =0 then 'Buzz'
            else num::text
       end
from generate_series(1,1000,1) AS gen(num);
```

[Array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) of options, cases cast to indices:

```
select (ARRAY[num::text,'Fizz','Buzz','FizzBuzz'])[ 1 +(num%3=0)::int +2*(num%5=0)::int]
from generate_series(1,1000,1) AS gen(num);
```

A combination of [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) with an array, keeps a static array without constructing it or prepending to it:

```
select coalesce( ('{Fizz,Buzz,FizzBuzz}'::text[])[ (num%3=0)::int +2*(num%5=0)::int ] 
                , num::text)
from generate_series(1,1000,1) AS gen(num);
```

[`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) of self-nullifying values:

```sql
select coalesce(case when num%15=0 then 'FizzBuzz' end,
                case when num%3 =0 then 'Fizz'     end,
                case when num%5 =0 then 'Buzz'     end,
                num::text)
from generate_series(1,1000,1) AS gen(num);
```

[`NATURAL LEFT JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)+[SRF](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html):

```lsq
select coalesce( f||b, f, b, a.num::text)
from    generate_series(1,1000,1)                AS a(num) natural left join 
(select generate_series(3,1000,3) num, 'Fizz' f) AS f      natural left join 
(select generate_series(5,1000,5) num, 'Buzz' b) AS b
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0aBzlaS0)